# Siu's arguments on Calabi-Yau theorem?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, complex-geometry

In Siu's Lecture note: [Lectures on Hermitian-Einstein metrics for stable bundles and Kahler-Einstein metrics](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/siu_HE_KE.pdf), he shows the $C^0$ and $C^2$ estimates of the complex Monge-Ampere equation on Riemannian manifold; and then uses Evans-Krylov's arguments to show Holder estimates for the second derivatives. But Chapter two §4 (p.100), he says "Let $u$ be a real-valued function on an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^m$".

My question is why it suffices to show the $C^{2,\alpha}$ estimate in euclidean space instead of the Riemannian manifold.